# Problem with updating array within function

Tags: javascript

I have been coding a Rubik's cube blindfolded memo generator, if you don't know what that is, you basically give it the scramble for a Rubik's cube, and it will give you back everything that you need to memorize to solve the cube blindfolded. Currently, it is just for solving the edges. How the blindfolded method works is you have one piece that you swap the edges with, this is the red/white edge, you always hold the cube with the green center facing you and the white center on the top. If you want a more detailed explanation watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ41gWvltT8.

My problem is in the console you get the correct memo, but the edges array doesn't seem to change, which makes no sense, I added a ton of comments to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Evman15/j9p8x6ws/2/), please help if you can, thanks in advance!

Here is the full js code (this is a console thing):

```
//NOTE: THIS IS ONLY FOR THE EDGES PART OF THE MEMO, SO FAR

//list of all the edge pairs on the rubiks cube
var edges = [
    ["a", "q"],
    ["b", "m"],
    ["c", "i"],
    ["d", "e"],
    ["e", "d"],
    ["f", "l"],
    ["g", "x"],
    ["h", "r"],
    ["i", "c"],
    ["j", "p"],
    ["k", "u"],
    ["l", "f"],
    ["m", "b"],
    ["n", "t"],
    ["o", "v"],
    ["p", "j"],
    ["q", "a"],
    ["r", "h"],
    ["s", "w"],
    ["t", "n"],
    ["u", "k"],
    ["v", "o"],
    ["w", "s"],
    ["x", "g"],
];

//a copy of the edges array, in its original state, 
//this is used to check where the edges need to be placed on the cube
const edgesOriginal = [
    ["a", "q"],
    ["b", "m"],
    ["c", "i"],
    ["d", "e"],
    ["e", "d"],
    ["f", "l"],
    ["g", "x"],
    ["h", "r"],
    ["i", "c"],
    ["j", "p"],
    ["k", "u"],
    ["l", "f"],
    ["m", "b"],
    ["n", "t"],
    ["o", "v"],
    ["p", "j"],
    ["q", "a"],
    ["r", "h"],
    ["s", "w"],
    ["t", "n"],
    ["u", "k"],
    ["v", "o"],
    ["w", "s"],
    ["x", "g"],
];

//swaps a given edge with the buffer edge(b)
function swapEdges(edge1, edge2) {
    var buffer2, swap2;
    //in the regular blindfolded method, the buffer piece that you
    //swap with is always the b/q edge, 12 represents the q side of it here
    buffer2 = 12

    //loop through the edges to find the number for the other side of the edge1 edge
    for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        if (edges[i][1] == edges[edge1][0]) {
            swap2 = i
        }
    }

    //a = 0, b = 1, c = 3 etc.
    console.log(buffer2, swap2, edge1, edge2)

    //swap both sides of the edge pieces using a temporary variable, 
    //[a, b] = [b, a] method was finnicky for some reason
    var temp = edges[edge1];
    edges[edge1] = edges[edge2];
    edges[edge2] = temp;

    temp = edges[buffer2];
    edges[buffer2] = edges[swap2];
    edges[swap2] = temp;
}

//takes a value from R, U, F, B, L, and D. You can add a ' or 2 to the end to make the move
//go the opposite direction or make it turn twice. Also I am too lazy to loop for the ' (this is called a prime move) moves
//all possible turns, note this is only for edges right now, I am almost certain this is working
function turn(side) {
    switch(side) {
        case "R":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        case "R'":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L'":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F'":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U'":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D'":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B'":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        case "R2":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L2":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F2":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U2":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D2":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B2":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        
    }
}

function doTurns(turns) {
    //remove whitespace
    var turnsFormated = turns.split(/\s/g);
    //loop through the turns to do
    for (var i = 0; i < turnsFormated.length; i++) {
        turn(turnsFormated[i])
        //console.log(turnsFormated[i])
    }
}

//literally just cylces four values in the edge array
function cycleFour(a, b, c, d) {
    [edges[a], edges[b], edges[c], edges[d]] = [edges[d], edges[a], edges[b], edges[c]];
}

//this is the weird part, when I look at the console, the memo is correct for what I am trying to do
//but the logged edge array doesnt seem to change :( please help
function generateMemo(scramble) {
    //scramble the cube
    doTurns(scramble);

    //this is the variable for the piece we need to swap with
    var currentBuffer;
    var memo = [];

    //in 3x3 blindfolded you go until you find the buffer in the lineup
    //and then you pick a random piece that you haven't already hit, and start on that
    //NOTE: currently this just goes until it finds the buffer piece (b/m)
    while (currentBuffer !== 1) {
        //search for where the piece that is in the 1/12 position, this is the position that you will swap all edges with
        //eventually solving all the edges into the correct position
        for (var i = 0; i < edgesOriginal.length; i++) {
            if (edgesOriginal[i][0] == edges[1][0]) {
                currentBuffer = i;
            }
        }
        //then swap the buffer with where it needs to go, putting the edge in the right spot
        swapEdges(currentBuffer, 1);
        console.log(edges, edgesOriginal);

        //this never triggers however the above console log shows them identical, please help :)
        if (edges == edgesOriginal) {
            console.log("yes")
        }

        // add the letter to the memo
        memo.push(getLetter(currentBuffer));
    }
    console.log(memo);
}

//converts a letter to the correct number to match the edgesOriginal array
function getLetter(num) {
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(num + 1 + 64);
      return letter;
}

//does exactly the opposite, converting the number to a letter I have no clue how this works btw, I just found it online
function getNumber(letter) {
    var number = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65 - 32;
    return number;
}
```

In short what I want to know is why does the edges variable not seem to change judging by the console logs, and why doesn't it print "yes" even if the console logs of that look the same.

Comment: I'm guessing that `generateMemo(scramble)` runs the whole thing, so what is placed in scramble?

Comment: yes, you're correct. scramble would be a list of moves such as (" R U F2 L' "), see https://solvethecube.com/notation for how the move notation works. In short there are letters for each side, R is right side, L is left, U is top (up), D is bottom (down). You can see a list of all the possible moves in the turn function.

Comment: Please provide input and expected output. `edges == edgesOriginal` will never be true unless they are referencing the same array.

Comment: Okay, say for instance I wanted to get the memo for the scramble "U F" (just a simple short scramble), it gives me the correct memo ("A D C F U P B"), but in the console, it looks like the edges array stays the same, and I thought that I was swapping the edges in the process, also even when the console prints that the arrays look identical the if statement doesn't print less. So to get that it would look like this: generateMemo("U F") and it prints the answer in the console, hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't stay the same, It ends the same but isn't that the goal? It starts scrambled then gets unscrambled... ? Maybe print them off on different lines so you can actually compare. Two objects / arrays aren't equal unless they're referencing the same object / array.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I was printing them on different parts in the program, I guess not?

Comment: Where exactly would I print it to see change in the console, currently the console logs of the edges array are the same?

Comment: Oh, if I use the jsfiddle I see change but not in chrome, weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following code snippet, it shows that there is change between the arrays. The reason that you don't see changes is because it is difficult for the human eye to catch things like this when it comes to large array's of text. Also, the changes are very small, most of it stays the same, but the change does exist.

Like what [@ChrisHamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12914833/chris-hamilton) said, "`edges == edgesOriginal` will never be true unless they are referencing the same array."

```js
//NOTE: THIS IS ONLY FOR THE EDGES PART OF THE MEMO, SO FAR

var outputArray = [];
var outputThis="";
function outputAr() {
  var result="";
  for (let i=0; i<arguments.length;i++) {
    if (i==0) {
      result+="[";
    }
    result+=arguments[i];
    if (i==(arguments.length-1)) {
      result+="]";
    }
  }
  outputArray.push(result);
}

//list of all the edge pairs on the rubiks cube
var edges = [
    ["a", "q"],
    ["b", "m"],
    ["c", "i"],
    ["d", "e"],
    ["e", "d"],
    ["f", "l"],
    ["g", "x"],
    ["h", "r"],
    ["i", "c"],
    ["j", "p"],
    ["k", "u"],
    ["l", "f"],
    ["m", "b"],
    ["n", "t"],
    ["o", "v"],
    ["p", "j"],
    ["q", "a"],
    ["r", "h"],
    ["s", "w"],
    ["t", "n"],
    ["u", "k"],
    ["v", "o"],
    ["w", "s"],
    ["x", "g"],
];

//a copy of the edges array, in its original state, 
//this is used to check where the edges need to be placed on the cube
const edgesOriginal = [
    ["a", "q"],
    ["b", "m"],
    ["c", "i"],
    ["d", "e"],
    ["e", "d"],
    ["f", "l"],
    ["g", "x"],
    ["h", "r"],
    ["i", "c"],
    ["j", "p"],
    ["k", "u"],
    ["l", "f"],
    ["m", "b"],
    ["n", "t"],
    ["o", "v"],
    ["p", "j"],
    ["q", "a"],
    ["r", "h"],
    ["s", "w"],
    ["t", "n"],
    ["u", "k"],
    ["v", "o"],
    ["w", "s"],
    ["x", "g"],
];

//swaps a given edge with the buffer edge(b)
function swapEdges(edge1, edge2) {
    var buffer2, swap2;
    //in the regular blindfolded method, the buffer piece that you
    //swap with is always the b/q edge, 12 represents the q side of it here
    buffer2 = 12

    //loop through the edges to find the number for the other side of the edge1 edge
    for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        if (edges[i][1] == edges[edge1][0]) {
            swap2 = i
        }
    }

    //a = 0, b = 1, c = 3 etc.
    console.log(buffer2, swap2, edge1, edge2)
    outputAr(buffer2, swap2, edge1, edge2);

    //swap both sides of the edge pieces using a temporary variable, 
    //[a, b] = [b, a] method was finnicky for some reason
    var temp = edges[edge1];
    edges[edge1] = edges[edge2];
    edges[edge2] = temp;

    temp = edges[buffer2];
    edges[buffer2] = edges[swap2];
    edges[swap2] = temp;
}

//takes a value from R, U, F, B, L, and D. You can add a ' or 2 to the end to make the move
//go the opposite direction or make it turn twice. Also I am too lazy to loop for the ' (this is called a prime move) moves
//all possible turns, note this is only for edges right now, I am almost certain this is working
function turn(side) {
    switch(side) {
        case "R":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        case "R'":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L'":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F'":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U'":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D'":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B'":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        case "R2":
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            cycleFour(12, 13, 14, 15);
            cycleFour(1, 19, 21, 9)
            break;
        case "L2":
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            cycleFour(4, 5, 6, 7);
            cycleFour(3, 11, 23, 17);
            break;
        case "F2":
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            cycleFour(8, 9, 10, 11);
            cycleFour(2, 15, 20, 5);
            break;
        case "U2":
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            cycleFour(0, 1, 2, 3);
            cycleFour(8, 4, 16, 12);
            break;
        case "D2":
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            cycleFour(20, 21, 22, 23);
            cycleFour(10, 14, 18, 6);
            break;
        case "B2":
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            cycleFour(16, 17, 18, 19);
            cycleFour(0, 7, 22, 13)
            break;
        
    }
}

function doTurns(turns) {
    //remove whitespace
    var turnsFormated = turns.split(/\s/g);
    //loop through the turns to do
    for (var i = 0; i < turnsFormated.length; i++) {
        turn(turnsFormated[i])
        //console.log(turnsFormated[i])
    }
}

//literally just cylces four values in the edge array
function cycleFour(a, b, c, d) {
    [edges[a], edges[b], edges[c], edges[d]] = [edges[d], edges[a], edges[b], edges[c]];
}

//this is the weird part, when I look at the console, the memo is correct for what I am trying to do
//but the logged edge array doesnt seem to change :( please help
function generateMemo(scramble) {
    //scramble the cube
    doTurns(scramble);

    //this is the variable for the piece we need to swap with
    var currentBuffer;
    var memo = [];

    //in 3x3 blindfolded you go until you find the buffer in the lineup
    //and then you pick a random piece that you haven't already hit, and start on that
    //NOTE: currently this just goes until it finds the buffer piece (b/m)
    while (currentBuffer !== 1) {
        //search for where the piece that is in the 1/12 position, this is the position that you will swap all edges with
        //eventually solving all the edges into the correct position
        for (var i = 0; i < edgesOriginal.length; i++) {
            if (edgesOriginal[i][0] == edges[1][0]) {
                currentBuffer = i;
            }
        }
        //then swap the buffer with where it needs to go, putting the edge in the right spot
        swapEdges(currentBuffer, 1);
        console.log(edges, edgesOriginal);
        outputAr(edges, edgesOriginal);

        //this never triggers however the above console log shows them identical, please help :)
        if (edges == edgesOriginal) {
            console.log("yes")
        }

        // add the letter to the memo
        memo.push(getLetter(currentBuffer));
    }
    console.log(memo);
    if (edges==edgesOriginal) {console.warn("yes");outputAr("yes");} else {console.error("no");outputAr("no");}
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=outputArray;
    for (let mnd=0;mnd<outputArray[1].length;mnd++) {
      outputThis+="<p>"+"<span>"+outputArray[1][mnd]+"</span>"+"<span>"+outputArray[3][mnd]+"</span>"+"<span>"+outputArray[5][mnd]+"</span>"+"<span>"+outputArray[7][mnd]+"</span>"+"<span>"+outputArray[9][mnd]+"</span>"+"</p>";
    }
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML=outputThis;
}

//converts a letter to the correct number to match the edgesOriginal array
function getLetter(num) {
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(num + 1 + 64);
      return letter;
}

//does exactly the opposite, converting the number to a letter I have no clue how this works btw, I just found it online
function getNumber(letter) {
    var number = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65 - 32;
    return number;
}

generateMemo(" R U F2 L' ");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
```